# Every "az" commands are now failing, how do I fix it?

Tags: azure, azure-cli2

I managed to break az, by using CTRL-C after the command "az login".  Now, all I can get is this message :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
  File "runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
  File "C:\Users\trdai\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-8jgnm5o1\azure-cli\azure\cli\__main__.py", line 32, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\trdai\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-8jgnm5o1\azure-cli-core\azure\cli\core\__init__.py", line 509, in get_default_cli
  File "C:\Users\trdai\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-8jgnm5o1\azure-cli-core\azure\cli\core\__init__.py", line 52, in __init__
  File "C:\Users\trdai\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-8jgnm5o1\azure-cli-core\azure\cli\core\_session.py", line 40, in load
  File "json\__init__.py", line 299, in load
  File "json\__init__.py", line 354, in loads
  File "json\decoder.py", line 339, in decode
  File "json\decoder.py", line 357, in raw_decode
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

[The command I use to get this message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ovorL.png)

Any idea on how to clean the cache?  I already tried to reinstall, to repair, to remove and reinstall again, with no success.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: remove the temporary folder for azure cli, something like `.azure` in user profile directory

Comment: Darn... so simple, yet it works perfectly.  Thank you!

Comment: For windows users: C:\Users\LOGIN-USER-NAME\.azure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case cleaning the temp folder (`/home/user/.azure`) solved the problem

Comment: In my case, it was just required to delete `az.sess` and `config` files from `.azure` folder